# Grafana Status timeline not working with PostgresSQL and only one Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, charts, grafana

I’m creating a dashboard in Grafana with data extracted from Google Servers and stored in a PostgresSQL Database.

In one of the visualization I would like to create a Status Timeline:
[image: StatusTimeline]
[image: StatusTimeline2]

I have created a query in PostgresSQL which returns me the following table:
[image: DataReturnedByPostGres]

As my understanding goes, that is the data that is need to create a Status Timeline. (Time, count of a variable and name of the variable count).
But when I copy that query inside Grafana, the chart is not the same as I have imagined:
[image: GrafanaVisualization]
I don’t know what else to do or how to fix it.

Does anyone has faced this issue before or know how to solve it, in order to get a Status Timeline like the one showed above?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your last image, the metric names used in the panel are the *column names*. The status values used are the *column values*. So you need a table result like that:

| executed_on | dev | asia-dev | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-07 12:00:00 | 1 | 4 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a "Partition by values" transform.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).